# ImportError: 'pyarrow' is required for converting a Sequence of date or datetime values to a PySeries

Tags: python, python-polars

I am using the code from "Polars - User Guide" in VSC.
Gives an error message: "ImportError: 'pyarrow' is required for converting a Sequence of date or datetime values to a PySeries"

Code:

```
import polars as pl

# to enrich the examples in this quickstart with dates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
# to generate data for the examples
import numpy as np 

dataframe = pl.DataFrame({"integer": [1, 2, 3], 
                          "date": [
                              (datetime(2022, 1, 1)), 
                              (datetime(2022, 1, 2)), 
                              (datetime(2022, 1, 3))
                          ], 
                          "float":[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]})
dataframe
```

[image]

can't find how to get past the error

Comment: Did you install the `pyarrow` module as the error suggests?

Comment: yes, but it didn't help

Comment: Odd. Did you restart your editor after installation? Can you `import pyarrow` directly to make sure it's installed?